# having trouble moving files to ~/bin

Tags: files

Firstly apologies if this is a stupid question, I am completely new to ubuntu. I've tried googling for the last hour but there is nothing that I can find that really explains this.

I've been searching around and it seems that the common place for binaries etc is ~/bin but I can't seem to locate the folder or move anything there in the terminal. If I try moving stuff there with mv folder ~/bin it just deletes it, so I can only assume that location doesn't exist?

I also don't seem to have the home/user path that I also see mentioned a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you trying to move to `~/bin`? If we know a little bit more about the problem you are trying to solve, we might be able to help you better :)

Comment: Just a install folder of phantomjs

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve by putting this folder on `~/bin`?

Comment: Currently I just have it in my downloads dir, I wanted to move it to a common place that I can keep my bins and that seemed like the goto location :)

Comment: You can just create a new folder called `bin` in your home folder. Just open the file manager, right-click, and new folder.

Comment: Yeah I've done this now, I just thought this folder might have meant to be there by default.

Using ~/bin doesn't find the folder but getting there by going cd user, cd bin, does work. As far as I can see it should be the exact same path

Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really want to have bin folder in your home directory, first create the folder using command

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

After following command is executed, then your mv command will work. What's most likely is happening is you don't have bin folder, but when you try to move, the file is moved as "bin" - that is your file now becomes bin.

If you want to move file "myscript.sh" to bin execute following command after making sure directory/folder exists.

```
mv myscript.sh ~/bin/.
```

Comment: Thanks I will do that in a minute. I assumed that due to all the content I found that mentioned that location that it would be there by default

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you are in the root directory**

When in the file browser, on the side there should be a panel, click on the computer button, there should be all the folders in your root directory, including bin and home.

Comment: It seems like OP wants to move to ~/bin, not sure root directory help. Besides you need to be privileged user to move to /bin directory